# Discrete Mathematics-set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the theorem "the complement of empty set is the universal set" , I know how it happens. But how can I prove it in contradiction method?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Proof:** Let $X=\{A: A \text{ is complement of empty set }\}$. We will prove that all the set is in $X$. If not. Then there exists a set $A$ such that $A$ is not in $X$, and hence $A$ is not complement of $\emptyset$. However $A=A\setminus \emptyset $. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain a contradiction just by using the definition of compliment of $\emptyset$ which is defined as $U\backslash\emptyset = \{x: x \in U \text { and } x \not \in \emptyset\}. $  Assume that you do not get $U$, then that implies that $\emptyset$ is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that @Paul did the answer as **you wanted**. However, you could do it directly:

$$x\in\emptyset'\Longleftrightarrow x\notin\emptyset\Longleftrightarrow \exists A(\neq\emptyset)\subseteq  U, x\in A\Longleftrightarrow x\in U$$